# How are sexual cues known by the brain?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, evolution, sexuality, communication

Sexual cues have been well established in evolutionary psychology as indicators of genetic compatibility/useful genes.

How does the human brain know that a cue is an indicator of a useful trait in order that a person perceives the trait as being an attractive one? What cognitive mechanisms are involved in the perception of sexual cues as being attractive?

Comment: It's probably about clues which visually signal health, youth and all else which is key for fertility - e.g. smooth skin, well developed muscles, etc. In the same manner the opposite, clues signalling weak health or age, get interpreted as sexually off-putting.